# How to trigger click/change events on input field after changing it's value when you don't know what events are being triggered

Tags: javascript, events, onchange, dom-events, userscripts

I have a Javascript code that modifies the value of input fields on a website that's not mine, and I need it to trigger all click and change events on those input fields when I modify the input field values.

But I may not know what functions they are calling when the events are triggered. Can this be done?

```
<input type = "text" id = "text" onchange="alert('alert')" value = "value">

<script>
document.getElementById("text").value = "new value";
console.log(document.getElementById("text").value);
</script>
```

Comment: If you can objectively identify all the elements you need, you can add attributes with calls to your functions.
You can use the console developer tools to check which functions are being called.
You can then redefine those functions or add your own alongside. It will work
I did a lot of web scraping and I know, pretty much anything can be done

Comment: @dprojects2050 Care to write an example as an answer? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure there are any events being triggered? If so, use the console dev tools to check for those. There is no a piece of code to check for such events. The console dev tools is the way.

Comment: @dprojects2050 I'm sure events are being triggered, I just don't know what events being triggered. I have been using the console dev tools for a while now, but I don't know how to check for events. How would I do that.

Comment: Try
`document.getElementById("text").click();`

This will simulate the "click" action, effectively triggering any events associated with the element.

Comment: @dprojects2050 Already tried that, there seems to be a different event associated with it. How would I use the console dev tools to check for events?

Comment: Most major browsers have this very common tool set that opens on F12. Find "Console" tab. 
Try this for a start:
`document.querySelectorAll("button.js-comment-edit.s-btn.s-btn__link")[0].click();`

This will click the "Edit" button on your last comment

Then, find "Performance" tab and start recording those actions that would trigger the functions you want to find. Stop the recording and go through the processes recorded over the period.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, use `EventTarget.dispatchEvent()` and specific event constructor to make an event what you want.

```
target.dispatchEvent(new InputEvent('change', { data: 'hello world' }));
```

check this jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/hentleman/h705zw6b/20/)

---

ref [1] : make event object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent)

ref [2] : dispatchEvent API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use "oninput" attribute to catch the events.

<input type="text" id="text" oninput="myFunction()">
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("text").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You wrote: " + x;
}
</script>
```